# Network interface not up

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, ethernet

Ethernet interface shows down. Tried to make it up with the below command, but still it shows down.

```
root@DLC-200:~# cat /sys/class/net/eth2/operstate
down
root@DLC-200:~# ifconfig eth2 up
root@DLC-200:~# cat /sys/class/net/eth2/operstate
down
```

Is there a way to make it up?

Comment: could you share `nmcli dev status` and `journalctl -u network` output

Comment: Is there a cable plugged into it?

Comment: Yes, wire is plugged-in. It is a customer unit, hence not supporting commands like nmcli or journalctl

Comment: show the interface configuration file, should be in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/eth2 ` or `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: `ifconfig` wont configure the interface, it will only enable it. try `ifup eth2`. Show the output of what happens there, you maybe haven't configured  the interface correctly.

Comment: @DeclanGallagher-  I don't see any such files. Also ifup not available.

Comment: @Ravi what operating system is this? Do you have administrative access root/sudo?

Comment: Its linux and I have root access. But most of the utilities are not part of the OS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80328/discussion-between-ravi-and-declan-gallagher).

Comment: Check dmesg for anything related to network devices. If the device doesn't appear, there is most probably a driver issue.